# Converts my own image data to TFRecords

Tags: tensorflow, image-preprocessing

now I am practicing to convert my own image data to TFRrcords for tensorflow.I am really new with tensorflow so I just modified the build_image_data.py which I got from Github.

This is some parts of the original code:

```
bazel-bin/inception/build_image_data \
      --train_directory="${TRAIN_DIR}" \
      --validation_directory="${VALIDATION_DIR}" \
      --output_directory="${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}" \
      --labels_file="${LABELS_FILE}" \
      --train_shards=128 \
      --validation_shards=24 \
      --num_threads=8
```

And I replace them with :

```
# convert the data.
bazel-bin/inception/build_image_data \
--train_directory=("C:/Dataset/Training data")
--validation_directory=("C:/Dataset/Test data")
--output_directory=("C:/Dataset/Trf")
--labels_file="C:/Dataset/Labels file"
--train_shards=128
--validation_shards=24
--num_threads=8
```

But I got an error as follows:

```
File "<ipython-input-12-4e5ff554c85f>", line 90
    bazel-bin/inception/build_image_data --train_directory=("C:/Dataset/Training data")
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Someone could help me, please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove parentheses around path:

```
bazel-bin/inception/build_image_data \
--train_directory="C:/Dataset/Training data"
--validation_directory="C:/Dataset/Test data"
--output_directory="C:/Dataset/Trf"
--labels_file="C:/Dataset/Labels file"
--train_shards=128
--validation_shards=24
--num_threads=8
```